# Saving a document in sql server 2008 database using .NET

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

Hi everybody I'm workin in .NET solution `Visual Basic` that makes reporting of a database using Crystal Reports for .NET, and I want to store each report after it been generated in the database in xml or in PDF just tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has an XML data type, so you might want to store these things in a column defined as XML.

It's generally not recommended to store BLOBs (such as PDFs) in a database unless you have a very compelling reason to do so.  I would stick with XML in your case.

**UPDATE**

You can work with XML in vb.net as a string, or better yet, as an [XML Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx).  You could send it to the database with the ToString() method and SQL Server will simply re-parse the thing and store it, as in:

```
mySqlCommandObject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mySqlParam", myXmlLiteral.ToString())
```

Comment: yeah thats what im gonna do, but can somone tell me how to do ti store xml data in vusual basic? ans retrive this data to view the document?

Comment: Please see my update and let me know if that answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports has a built-in "save as" or "export" feature.